# Use External Json Data from a File to show a d3.js Pie chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have to design a Pie chart, which dynamically updates when changes are made in an external JSON file. I have written a fairly simple code, but somehow I am not getting the chart rendered on the chrome page. There seems to be some Uncaught errors and definition of "data" missing. I am fairly new to d3 and Javascript, and I need your assistance in debugging/fixing this code for me.
My Json file is called by the d3.json method call. 
x in the json file is Name and y is Value. x,y becomes my name:Value pair.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
    <script src="../lib/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var width = 960; 
        var height = 500; 
        var radius = 400;

        var outerRadius = radius;
        var innerRadius = 0;

        var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).y(function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
                "height", height).append("g").attr("transform",
                "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc").data(pie(data)).enter().append("g").attr(
                "class", "arc");

        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(outerRadius)
                .innerRadius(innerRadius);

        var labelArc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - 40).innerRadius(
                radius - 40);

        d3.json("data.json", function(error, data ) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {

                d.x = d.x;

                d.y = d.y+d.y;

                x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                }));

                y.domain([ 0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                    return d.y;
                }) ]);

                g.append("path")

                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                }).attr("d", arc);

                g.append("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")";
                }).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.x;
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: where is this data.json file. You need provide relative path to the file data.json, or place it along this html in the same folder

Comment: The data.json file is in the same folder as this HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

There is some logical issues with code structure... like the data variable is used outside d3.json where it isnt accessible. See the approach below... it should work, I havent tested it. Let me know if u face any issues running this code

```
    var width = 960; 
    var height = 500; 
    var radius = 400;

    var outerRadius = radius;
    var innerRadius = 0;

    var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).y(function(d) {
        return d.y;
    });

    var g, arc, labelArc;

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
            "height", height).append("g").attr("transform",
            "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");



    d3.json("data.json", function(error, data ) {

        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));

        y.domain([ 0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; }) ]);

        g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                   .data(pie(data))
                   .enter()
                   .append("g")
                   .attr("class", "arc");

        arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
                    .innerRadius(innerRadius);

        labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
                         .outerRadius(radius - 40)
                         .innerRadius(radius - 40);

        g.append("path")
         .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
         .attr("d", arc);

        g.append("text")
         .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")";})
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d) { return d.data.x; });        

    });
```